# Change scroll behavior when use transform: rotate() CSS property ngx-owl-carousel-o

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, owl-carousel

I have some issues with scrolling when use transform: rotate(180deg) CSS property in body related to carousel

At Moment Scroll is working good LTR when rotate screen need to as LTR for viewing person

```
[Please See Demo](https://codepen.io/derciesto/pen/MWPoWpw)
```

Comment: Please put enough code into your question so we can see the problem. If you leave it on an external site, when that site is corrected or removed your question will be useless for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And please explain more what element it is that you are rotating.